# ThreadSafe FIFO List with Automatic Size Limit Management

Tags: c#, list, queue

I'm trying to figure out what data type to use...
Basically I want a FIFO queue that is thread-safe and will automatically throw out old enough items once it gets to a pre-specified limit.

Well, actually, maybe more of a list, because I don't want the whole concept of pushing onto the queue and popping an item off the queue at which point it's no longer available.

The use case is basically for a playlist where I would have up to 5 upcoming items, the currently playing item, and then about 20 items that have already played.  Hence, why I guess it cannot be a queue, I would be accessing one of the items in the middle as the "current" item. And I would rather not have to manually manage throwing away old items when the list gets to big... obviously I could write this all myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if this already exists for C#.

Any ideas of what I could use?

Comment: I did a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031718/how-to-limit-blockingcollection-size-but-keep-adding-new-itens-net-limited-siz), I want the same thing, a limited size Thread-safe FIFO. Have you come to a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Framework there is something almost having the functionality you want - the [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) . It is thread-safe queue with most operations being implemented lock-free, so it is very fast.

The only function is does not have is the "limit" with automatic "throw-away"...

But that can be easily added - just create you own class containing a private `ConcurrentQueue` and implement the "throw-away part" in your public enqueue method by Dequeuing/throwing away till your limit is satisfied before Enqueuing the new element.

**EDIT - as per comment**:
One option would be to make the second "Queue" an `ObservableCollection` - though not inherently thread-safe (beware) this would be easily bind in WPF...

Another would be to make your class implement the [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) interface (which consists of `IList<T>,  ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged`) accordingly - that sounds alot, but most of these you get easily implemented by relaying to the internal `ConcurrentQueue` so there is not much real code to write...
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Maybe for the accessing the middle part I can create an object with two queues... one that contains the upcoming items and another that is the played items list.  Would be really great if I can get this to work with WPF binding...

Answer (score 2):

You might try [`new ReplaySubject<T>(int count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229429.aspx) from Rx, which buffers the last `count` objects from the stream of observed events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229429.aspx

If you need a more conventional programming model (Rx is a little out there) then maybe try TPL DataFlow [`BroadcastBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447.aspx).  Broadcast is named as in TV broadcast - if a frame isn't 'processed' fast enough it is dropped, so processing stays relevant with respect 'live' frame.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447.aspx

UPDATE: ReplaySubject replays the first X, it is not a FIFO queue it is a 'First X List'.