# How to limit BlockingCollection size but keep adding new itens (.NET limited size FIFO)?

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, lru

I want to limit the size of the BlockingCollection. If I want to add another item and the collection is full, the oldest must be removed. Is there some Class specific to this task or my solution is ok?

```
        BlockingCollection<string> collection = new BlockingCollection<string>(10);

        string newString = "";
        //Not an elegant solution?
        if (collection.Count == collection.BoundedCapacity)
        {
            string dummy;
            collection.TryTake(out dummy);
        }
        collection.Add(newString);
```

EDIT1: Similar question here: [ThreadSafe FIFO List with Automatic Size Limit Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142247/threadsafe-fifo-list-with-automatic-size-limit-management)

Comment: That's not a thread-safe collection anymore, what will be removed is entirely unpredictable.  Quacks like a cache instead, check out the MemoryCache class.

Comment: What is it you're aiming to accomplish? Can you just throw away the removed item without doing anything with it?

Comment: @Hans Passant, hey! You are everywhere! :) I'm not getting why it is not thread safe anymore...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I need to consume the most updated items and the consumer/produced speed may vary a bit.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a LRU cache.  There is no implementation that I know of in the standard libraries but would not be hard to create.  Look at this c++ [implementation](http://timday.bitbucket.org/lru.html) for some clues.

---

Edit

Try [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23396/A-High-Performance-Multi-Threaded-LRU-Cache) from code project

Comment: Thank you, but this solution is kind of wold (2008). The Author have commented it: This is an interesting idea...
"The ConcurrentDictionary may perform better than my solution (which was written several years prior to that class becoming available). If anyone has the time to alter this and run preformance tests I would love to see the results."

Answer (score 2):

Your solution will function correctly, but it is not thread safe.  `BlockingCollection<T>` does not provide a mechanism to handle this directly.

Your solution may still block (if another thread calls `Add()` after your `TryTake`) or potentially remove an extra item (if another thread removes while you're also removing).

Comment: I tough BlockingCollection was thread safe. From MSDN:  "BlockingCollection<T> is a thread-safe collection class that provides the following features:" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx What I'm missing here?

Comment: @Pedro77 BlockingCollection **is** thread safe, it's your usage of the collection that isn't.  Your solution can easily lead to having fewer items or a block, since you're not locking and not using the methods directly on BC in a single method call.

Comment: can you please clarify? I'm a BlockingCollection newbie, I can't see the deadlock... Each thread can only add or remove, not both?

Comment: @Pedro77 Say you're at bounded capacity.  Thread 1 hits if, sees that, enters block, calls TryTake.  Now you're boundedCapacity-1 - thread 2 does check, sees it's okay, both threads try to call .Add(), but one will block because the BlockingCollection will be at capacity as soon as the first hits.

Comment: Oh, I see, but only one thread is adding, so it will never happen.

Comment: @Pedro77 Then your solution is probably fine... (Still can end up with too FEW items, if a separate thread consumes items in between your checks)